# FinancialIndicator does not work in InteractiveTradingChart with list form of stock data

Tags: time-series, financialdata

I want to add some `FinancialIndicator` on `InteractiveTradingChart` when stock data is written in the form of list, `{date, {o,h,l,c,v}}`.

If I directly use a ticker symbol (for example, `^NKY`), I can easily add `FinancialIndicator`:

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{"^NKY", {{2023, 3, 1}, {2023, 3,10}}}, {FinancialIndicator["ExponentialMovingAverage"]}]
```

This command gives a correct financial indicator (a moving average), this case is no problem:
[image]

Let us now use a list form of stock data, instead of ticker symbol:

```
stockdata = {{{2023, 3, 1}, {27363.6, 27530.8, 27305.4, 27516.5, 0}}, {{2023, 3, 2}, {27564.8, 27617.8, 27408.5, 27498.9, 0}}, {{2023, 3,3}, {27683.3, 27961.2, 27655.3, 27927.5, 0}},{{2023, 3,6}, {28182.3, 28288.6, 28153.8, 28237.8, 0}}, {{2023, 3,7}, {28202.6, 28398.3, 28202.6, 28309.2, 0}}, {{2023, 3,8}, {28237.2, 28469.4, 28232.7, 28444.2, 0}}, {{2023, 3,9}, {28648.1, 28734.8, 28558.9, 28623.2, 0}}, {{2023, 3,10}, {28385.3, 28424.2, 28118.7, 28118.7, 0}}}
```

This `stockdata` has same dates and ohlcv shown in the first figure.
Now, when I plot this data,

```
InteractiveTradingChart[stockdata, {FinancialIndicator["ExponentialMovingAverage"]}]
```

there is no financial indicator:
[image]

I do not know how to fix the problem. I want to use `stockdata` form, not ticker symbol form.

My mathematica version is

```
$Version
```

`13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)`

Any comment is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I can reproduce the issue with Mathematica 13.2.1 on Pop!_OS 22.04.

As I am a frequent user of the InteractiveTradingChart myself, I have reached out to the Wolfram Technical Support. They confirmed that it is indeed a bug.

As a temporary workaround, they have offered the following solution:

```
Dynamic[
  RawBoxes[
    Charting`iInteractiveTradingChart[
      InteractiveTradingChart,
      stockdata,
      List[
        FinancialIndicator["ExponentialMovingAverage", 10]
      ],
      Automatic
    ]
  ],
  Rule[
    SingleEvaluation,
    True
  ]
]
```

Comment: I also reported the issue to Wolfram Mathematica support against Mathematica 13.2.1, in this, on Windows 10 Pro 22H2 with current patches. I do note that using InteractiveTradingChart one can go the bottom of the chart select indicators > statistical > ExponentialMovingAverage and then it works.

Comment: @Hans-Peter, Thank you very much for your comment. This tentative solution works fine. I expect Wolfram research team will fix the issue soon.

Comment: @IAmANaïf Thank you also!